# Make link Ajax.ActionLink in MVC 4

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, episerver-7

Beeing new to Ajax i need help with how to add the querystring and invoke the Index action without a postback. Now the link looks like this:

```
<a href="@EPiServer.UriSupport.AddQueryString(Request.RawUrl, "section", Server.UrlEncode(sectionGroup.Term))">@sectionGroup.Term, @sectionGroup.Count</a>
```

My guess is using Ajax.ActionLink but how do i create the querystring?

Comment: What do you mean by "make this link use AJAX"?  What are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I want to add a querystring and invoke the index action without a postback.

Answer (score 1):

Everything that you add to the routeValues and doesn't match a route segment will be added to the querystring.

Using your example, it would look something like this with `Ajax.ActionLink`:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
    sectionGroup.Term + ", " + sectionGroup.Count, 
    "Index", 
    new { section = sectionGroup.Term }, 
    new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "id-of-container" }
)
```

In your Index action you need to return a partial view when it is requested with ajax. This will remove the layout (master page) from the response.

```
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    return PartialView(model);

return View(model);
```

Remember to add a reference to the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` file.